# UITableView prototype cell does not becomes clickable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am working with storyboard. I created a viewcontroller that has UITableView and created a prototype cell. And added another UIViewController. I click prototype cell and drag to new UIViewController to make a push screen action. It seems everything is ok. Storyboard has these two UIViewControllers and there is a link from first to second. But when I run the application, even there are some rows in tableview, there is not right arrow in rows. And, when I click the row, second viewcontroller does not come to screen. What can be the reason ?

(note: storyboard has another viewcontrollers. all others work well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. you have to give a identifier to prototype cell in storyboard.